# Forbidden indicator appears after upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, 16.10

After upgrading Ubuntu release to 16.10 one indicator appears in after login:

[image]

This problem appears in my system and my friend after upgrading Ubuntu

Comment: When you click on it, what does it say?

Comment: @Michal nothing!